# Android: Create NinePatchDrawable from resources

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make a NinePatchDrawable object from a NinePatch image I made in my /drawable resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `getResources().getDrawable()`, supplying the ID of the drawable resource. Quoting the docs for [`getDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29):

> Various types of objects will be returned depending on the underlying resource -- for example, a solid color, PNG image, scalable image, etc. The Drawable API hides these implementation details.